# Pip command crashes Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip, cython

I am trying to install [Cython](https://cython.org/) in `Windows 10`. I followed below steps to do so

**Step 1**: Installed [python 3.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) (3.6.8), It is installed at the below path

```
C:\Users\Atinesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
```

**Step 2**: Configured `pip` by Setting below path to the `environment variable`

```
C:\Users\Atinesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

Now whenever I use `pip` to install any package, for example

```
pip install cython
```

I get these errors

[image]

[image]

Even If I issue `pip` command from [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), I get the same errors. Any suggestions would be of great help I am stuck at this from past 2 days.

Comment: Have you tried calling support person and giving them the error?

Comment: I real don't think it should be possible to get a blue screen error from a Python "ModuleNotFound" exception. Something's more dramatically wrong here...